Azure Static Web App with Git Actions [Git Actions error]
I'm trying to host my personal portfolio website with Azure Cloud(Static Web Actions) and I'm facing an error from Git Actions.
my yaml file - https://github.com/OfficialCodeVoyage/pavlobondarenko.co/blob/pushtoazure/.github/workflows/azure-static-web-apps-lively-ocean-008ed2910.yml
repo - https://github.com/OfficialCodeVoyage/pavlobondarenko.co/tree/pushtoazure
error 1
error 2
Tried changing .yaml file
removed dokerfile
removed php call for now
Thank you in advance!

Next time please post code and exceptions as text in the question itself. Questions should be self-contained, not depend on external transient sources and images should not be used to display text.

I tried your code, made few changes, and was able to deploy the app to Azure Static web app via GitHub actions.
This is my .yml file :
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_POLITE_ROCK_062CA360F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/"
          api_location: ""
          output_location: "." 

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_POLITE_ROCK_062CA360F }}
          action: "close"

I deployed the app through Github.

This is local output:

Here's the output after deployment:


Hello. What exactly did you change?

I added output_location= "." in the .yml file.
